# Oracle SQL - update 2 columns in row with the oldest date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to update 2 columns in a row.  The row that should be updated is the row that has the oldest `duedate`

The table chorecompletion is described as:

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CHOREID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 GROUPID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 DUEDATE                                   NOT NULL DATE
 COMPLETEDDATE                                      DATE
 COMPLETEDBY                                        NUMBER(38)
```

This query returns the row that I want to update

```
select *
from 
(
        select choreid, duedate, row_number() 
        over (partition by choreid order by duedate) as rn 
        from chorecompletion where choreid = 12 and groupid = 6
)
where rn = 1;
```

Where I could use some help  is how to use this query in my update statement, specifically my where clause

my current attempt:

```
update chorecompletion 
set completeddate = sysdate, completedby=1
where --How to get the result of the previous query here?
```

Any help on my logic would be hugely appreciated.

Example desired result:

Before Update:

```
CHOREID      GROUPID    DUEDATE     COMPLETEDDATE      COMPLETEDBY
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  12          6        2018-11-1
  12          6        2018-10-1
```

After Update

```
CHOREID      GROUPID    DUEDATE     COMPLETEDDATE      COMPLETEDBY
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  12          6        2018-11-1 
  12          6        2018-10-1      2018-09-30            1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> create table test
  2  (choreid number,
  3   groupid number,
  4   duedate date,
  5   completeddate date,
  6   completedby number
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select 12, 6, date '2018-01-11', null, null from dual union all
  3    select 12, 6, date '2018-01-10', null, null from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> update test t set
  2    t.completeddate = sysdate,
  3    t.completedby = 1
  4  where t.duedate = (select min(t1.duedate)
  5                     from test t1
  6                     where t1.choreid = t.choreid
  7                       and t1.groupid = t.groupid)
  8    and t.choreid = 12
  9    and t.groupid = 6;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From test;

   CHOREID    GROUPID DUEDATE    COMPLETEDD COMPLETEDBY
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
        12          6 2018-01-11
        12          6 2018-01-10 2018-09-30           1

SQL>
```

Comment: This ended up being the easiest solution for me to implement.  At first it wasn't working, but I realized it was because in my sample data set I already had the same choreid and groupid with a `completeddate` and `completedby`, so your solution was simply updating the already completed results.  adding the the line `and completeddate is null` in the nested inner query fixed this for me.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MERGE` statement and can join on the `ROWID` pseudo-column so that you can correlated directly to the matched row:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8727ed/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE chorecompletion ( choreid, groupid, duedate, completeddate, completedby ) AS
  SELECT 12, 6, DATE '2018-09-29', CAST( null AS DATE ), CAST( null AS NUMBER ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 6, DATE '2018-09-30', null, null FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
MERGE INTO chorecompletion dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid
  FROM   (
    SELECT *
    FROM   chorecompletion
    WHERE  choreid = 12
    AND    groupid = 6
    ORDER BY duedate ASC
  )
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1
) src
ON ( src.RID = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET completeddate = sysdate,
      completedby   = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8727ed/6/0)**:

```
1 Row Updated.
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM chorecompletion
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8727ed/6/1)**:

```
| CHOREID | GROUPID |              DUEDATE |        COMPLETEDDATE | COMPLETEDBY |
|---------|---------|----------------------|----------------------|-------------|
|      12 |       6 | 2018-09-29T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T18:42:45Z |           1 |
|      12 |       6 | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |               (null) |      (null) |
```

**Query 3**: You could also use an `UPDATE` statement with the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```
UPDATE chorecompletion dst
SET    completeddate = sysdate,
       completedby   = 2
WHERE  ROWID = (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY choreid ORDER BY duedate ) rn
    FROM   chorecompletion
    WHERE  choreid = 12
    AND    groupid = 6
    ORDER BY duedate ASC
  )
  WHERE rn = 1
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8727ed/6/2)**:

```
1 Row Updated.
```

**Query 4**:

```
SELECT * FROM chorecompletion
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8727ed/6/3)**:

```
| CHOREID | GROUPID |              DUEDATE |        COMPLETEDDATE | COMPLETEDBY |
|---------|---------|----------------------|----------------------|-------------|
|      12 |       6 | 2018-09-29T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T18:42:45Z |           2 |
|      12 |       6 | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |               (null) |      (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery.  If I understand correctly:

```
update chorecompletion
    set completeddate = (select min(duedate)
                         from chorecompletion cc
                         where cc.choreid = chorecompletion.coreid
                        )
    where choreid = 12 and groupid = 6
```

Comment: That `=` after `set`, is that some syntax I don't know or a mistake?

Comment: This will set the completed date to the earliest due date of with the same `choreid` (which is not what the OP wants) but it also does not correlate the earliest due date to have a `groupid` of 6 so you may get a `duedate` that does not fit with the data.